# How to remove trailing slash after applying filters - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql

How do I remove the trailing slash after applying a filter in Wordpress? I've tried everything but couldn't find a solution.

current url => **https://example.com/category/?orderby=popularity**
and I want it to be like this: **https://example.com/category?orderby=popularity**

Thanks in advance,

I tried finding the code in template files but couldn't find the element with that class or id name anywhere.

Comment: Likely this isn't hard-coded anywhere, but simply the result of submitting a form that uses method=GET, and either has it's action set to that URL, or left completely empty. If you are "on" the URL `https://example.com/category/` already when you submit this, of course you get the slash in the resulting form submission URL as well. You'd rather need to see to it that WP creates links to your categories without a trailing slash in the first place then.

Comment: (Are you really using WordPress with a PostgreSql database? Probably not impossible, I suppose, there have been some "adapters" to use WP with databases other than MySQL/MariaDB ... but if that is not actually the case here, then please tag appropriately.)